# Can conky float over maximized windows?

Tags: kde, desktop, conky, panel

My idea is to use a minimized conky window on the desktop to show basically CPU and memory data all the time. Is this possible with Conky?

Comment: If I understand your question properly, this sounds like a window manager feature. The window manager would pin conky as on top of everything else, even when not focused. What window manager are you using?

Comment: I use KDE 4.8.1

Comment: I'm surprised this hasnt gotten an answer yet. However if it doesnt, you might try in superuser as they tend to be more geared towards desktops, while here is a bit more focused towards servers. KDE should definitely be capable of doing this though.

Comment: This should be possible using the window behavior settings, though accessing those might be tricky, given that Conky does not request a border.

Comment: I believe you just have to find the right window manager hints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's possible.

In the old times, I run xfwm4 with a fixed margin left on top side, now I just set the window type to `panel` in conky, the screen margin is no longer required.

Comment: I can confirm this behavior with Gnome's `metacity` as well.

Answer (score 1):

KDE can be configured to keep any window always on top of other windows. Just right-click the window chrome and select `Advanced -> Keep Above Others`. You can configure this to be the default for new Conky windows in `Advanced -> Special Window Settings -> Arrangement & Access -> Keep Above`.

Answer (score 0):

I have a shortcut to display conky and the only way it can be displayed on top of maximized windows is to use `wmctrl` to raise it after the panel has been spawned:

```
function toggleConky {
    if pidof conky | grep [0-9] > /dev/null
    then
        killall conky    # If conky is already running, kill it
    else
        # Otherwise start it
        conky &          # Run in background
        sleep 0.1        # wait for it to load
        wmctrl -a conky  # raise it to the top
    fi
}
```

For this to work Conky has to be called "conky":

```
own_window yes
own_window_title conky
own_window_hints undecorated,above,sticky # doesn't do the trick
own_window_type panel
```

Answer (score 0):

In Fedora 32 this would make conky window on top

```
own_window_type = 'dock'
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. You may want to add instructions on where to put this configuration setting, as not all readers may be familiar enough.